# how to view json data in ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

hi i have json data which i wanted to show on my Ionic 2 App , but i am not able to show few data from the json data. every thing is working fine but jst i am not able to view few data. data of classes and days from json data.

1. json data link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzjLMYUKOU1mc1loVVpWbmxvVFU/view
2. ionic 2 html 
   file link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzjLMYUKOU1mUWFHZVFHVXB4T3M/view
3. ionic 2 html file ts link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzjLMYUKOU1mTFdNdFJMeGdjWTQ/view

   ionic 2 html code

   ## Train Between Station

   ```
   <ion-card-content >
     <div *ngFor="let tra of train1">
     <h3><b>Train: {{tra.no}}</b></h3><br>
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td><b>Train Name :-  </b> </td>
           <td>{{tra.name}}</td>
           <br>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td><b>Train No :-  </b></td>
           <td>{{tra.number}}</td>
           <br>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td><b>Source Station Name :-  </b></td>
            <td>{{tra.from.name}}</td>
            <br>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td><b>Destination Station Name :-  </b></td>
            <td>{{tra.to.name}}</td>
            <br>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td><b>Source Departure Time :-  </b></td>
            <td>{{tra.src_departure_time}}</td>
            <br>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td><b>Destination Arrivali Time:-  </b></td>
            <td>{{tra.dest_arrival_time}}</td>
            <br>
      </tr>
    </table>

      <table border="1" text-center width="100%">
       <tr>
         <td><b>Class</b></td> 
         <td><b>a1</b></td> 
         <td><b>a2</b> </td>
         <td><b>3a</b> </td>
         <td><b>4a</b> </td>
         <td><b>5a</b> </td>
         <td><b>6a</b> </td>
         <td><b>7a</b> </td>
         <td><b>a8</b> </td>


       </tr>
           <tr  >
               <td *ngFor="let ca of class_arr">{{train1[ca].classes.available}}</td>
           </tr>
    </table>
   ```

   ```
      <table border="1" text-center width="100%">
       <tr>
           <td><b>Day's</b></td> 
           <td><b>SUN</b></td>
           <td><b>MON</b></td> 
           <td><b>TUE</b></td>
           <td><b>WED</b></td> 
           <td><b>THU</b></td>
           <td><b>FRI</b></td> 
           <td><b>SAT</b></td>
       </tr>
       <tr >
         <!--<td><b>Runs</b></td> -->
           <td>y</td>
           <td>y</td>
           <td>n</td>
           <td>y</td>
           <td>n</td>
           <td>y</td>
           <td>n</td>
           <td>y</td>

       </tr>
    </table>
   ```

   ionic 2 ts code:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

   /*
     Generated class for the TrainBwStationDetails page.

     See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
     Ionic pages and navigation.
   */
   @Component({
     selector: 'page-train-bw-station-details',
     templateUrl: 'train-bw-station-details.html'
   })
   export class TrainBwStationDetailsPage {
   TrainBwStation:any;
   train1:any;
   train_total:any;
   class_arr:any[];
   days_arr:any[];
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
     {


       this.TrainBwStation=this.navParams.get("data");

     }

     ionViewDidLoad() {
       console.log('ionViewDidLoad TrainBwStationDetailsPage');
     }


   }
   ```

   json data:

   ```
   {
       "train": [
           {
               "number": "16587",
               "to": {
                   "code": "FA",
                   "name": "FALNA"
               },
               "classes": [
                   {
                       "available": "Y",
                       "class-code": "2A"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "N",
                       "class-code": "2S"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "Y",
                       "class-code": "SL"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "N",
                       "class-code": "1A"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "N",
                       "class-code": "FC"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "N",
                       "class-code": "CC"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "N",
                       "class-code": "3E"
                   },
                   {
                       "available": "Y",
                       "class-code": "3A"
                   }
               ],
               "days": [
                   {
                       "runs": "Y",
                       "day-code": "MON"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "N",
                       "day-code": "TUE"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "N",
                       "day-code": "WED"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "N",
                       "day-code": "THU"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "N",
                       "day-code": "FRI"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "Y",
                       "day-code": "SAT"
                   },
                   {
                       "runs": "N",
                       "day-code": "SUN"
                   }
               ],
               "src_departure_time": "07:50",
               "name": "YPR-BKN BI WEEKLY EXP SPL",
               "from": {
                   "code": "KYN",
                   "name": "KALYAN JN"
               },
               "no": 1,
               "dest_arrival_time": "21:46",
               "travel_time": "13:56"
           },

       ],
       "error": "",
       "response_code": 200,
       "total": 7
   }
   ```

Comment: Why can't you paste your code on your question? links will not help to you.

Comment: i thought i will look messy that's why

Comment: No.Please go ahead and do that.Stackoverflow is for code demonstration.Not for the external links.

Comment: @Sampath i have added code and i have aded smaller part of json data coz it was so much data but still the train part is repeating

Comment: Your mapping in the html does not match your json data or your component.. where is `train1` set?

Comment: @suraj the classes and days part from json data i wanted to show that other part is done

Comment: @suraj  classes and days that data is repeated in my main json code and i wanted to show that in table form

Comment: As mentioned, JSON and your html do not match. Please check the correct JSON for us to help youor actually I mean that what exactly does `train1` contain?

Answer (score 0):

For `classes` you have to do like below.Here `tra` is your root object.

```
<tr >
  <td *ngFor="let ca of tra.classes">{{ca.available}}</td>
</tr>
```

For `days` you have to do like below.Here `tra` is your root object.

```
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let d of tra.days">{{d.day-code}}</td>
</tr>
```